Is it possible to get a Linux CAN driver to not respond to missing CRC or CRC errors on CAN messages?
I have a device on a CAN bus that is either not sending CRCs or sending corrupted CRCs in certain scenarios.  The device is 3rd-party so cannot be altered.  I don't mind if Linux ignores the malformed frame, but it needs to not generate an error frame.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Does this happen in the driver or in the CAN controller chip?
Also not sure if this is something I can control using a SocketCAN API or via a command line call to ip link.

It turns out that the problem was that the timing of the other device was slightly off, and setting the SJW (sync jump width) to 4 (instead of 1) fixed the problem.  Apparently, some clocks on CAN controllers can be problematic, or, in this particular case, can start to get problematic when heated.  On slower CAN settings (I'm running my bus at 250k), having a larger SJW can give the CAN chips more tolerance and help prevent this from causing problems.
The actual command I issued to fix it was (using canE as the device - yours is probably can0):
ip link set down canE
ip link set canE type can tq 50 prop-seg 37 phase-seg1 32 phase-seg2 10 sjw 4
ip link set up canE

The last part ("sjw 4") is the change, and other values in this command I just got from showing the details from the can port:
ip -statistics -details link show canE

I just repeated those values but set the SJW to 4.  I don't know much about these timings, but the Kernel CAN README has some information as well as links to other documents.

You really shouldn't need to set SJW to 4 at 250k or you have severe timing problems in the system. It is not a solution to your problem, it is a solution to a symptom caused by your actual problem. Sounds like you or someone else is using the wrong clock source oscillator. You should be using quartz for higher baudrates. Or otherwise some node is using a non-standard sample point. A summary of the most common design mistakes can be found here: What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?

This "can tq 50 prop-seg 37 phase-seg1 32 phase-seg2 10 sjw 4" is nonsense btw. The CAN standard mandates a maximum tq of 25. Where 1 tq ("time quanta") is a fraction of a bit length. Why would you divide a bit length into 100 units? You don't have that kind of real-time accuracy for sure. Or are you using some manner of OCXO in a super tight real-time system? Linux does not fit into the picture at all then.

@Lundin - indeed the problem in this case was a CAN-controlled valve in the system.  It appears that its clock starts deviating when it is heated.  This actually appears to be a manufacturing defect, as not every valve we tested exhibited this behavior.  In any case, loosening the sjw fixed the problem.  It actually works at sjw=2 but we settled on sjw=3 in case it got worse than our test case.

@Lundin - As for the rest, all of the parameters except SJW came from the default settings of the CAN controller.  The command line syntax requires they all be set at once, which was why the command specifies them all.

This is handled by the CAN controller hardware so there is probably nothing you can do on the software side of things, short of resetting error counters/restarting the controller.
